# Не открывается страница сайта на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет.

При попытке зайти в админку сайта выдает:

> Service is temporarily unavailable
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Сам же сайт работает и большинство внутренних страниц отображается. Такая же надпись выдается, если попытаться зайти в разделы, которые требуют авторизации.

Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Это сервак пишет скорее всего, копай логи.

Comment: Обычно сервер, но я думал что если проблема на сервере то это отображается на всем сайте. У меня же главная и некоторые разделы нормально открываются.

Может быть такое что проблема в Битриксе? Или это точно на стороне сервера?